# Take two arrays and make them into key - value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays as follows.

```
idOne =  ["6", "6", "11"]
counts =  ["2", "1", "1"]
```

How would I make this into a associative array with idOne being the key and counts being the value?

Comment: try this function: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_combine/

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays.

Comment: Well, okay. How do I make the idOne the key and the counts variable value?

Comment: What do you want to have `associativeArray["6"]` return? Should it contain `["2", "1"]`?

Comment: @Dan Wich It should return the first value in the counts array.

Comment: @wowzuzz Why wouldn't it also return the 2nd, since there can be only one `associativeArray["6"]`

Comment: @DanWich Yes it should contain Object {6: "2", 6: "1" , 11: "1"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(updated based on your comments)

```
var totalsByID = {};
for(var i = 0; i < idOne.length; i++) {
   var id = idOne[i];
   var count = parseInt(counts[i]);
   if(totalsByID[id] === undefined) {
      // We have no entry for this ID, so create one
      totalsByID[id] = count;
   } else {
      // We already have an entry for this ID, so we need to add our current count to it
      totalsByID[id] += count;
   }
}
```

plalx suggested an alternate structure that includes your arrays for testing:

```
var idOne = ["6", "6", "11"],
    counts = ["2", "1", "1"],
    totalsById = {},
    i = 0,
    len = idOne.length,
    k;

for(; i < len; i++) {
   k = idOne[i];

   //initialize the total to 0
   totalsById[k] = totalsById[k] || 0;

   //you could remove the parseInt call if your count values were numbers instead of strings
   totalsById[k] += parseInt(counts[i], 10);
}
```

Comment: I get this back on my console.log
Object {6: "2", 11: "1"} 
Where is the other 6? I assume this is because its not foreach but for?

Comment: That's what you're supposed to get. You have duplicated keys, and a KEY by definition should be unique. That's your main problem right there.

Comment: elclanrs is correct, JavaScript can't have an object with two "keys" of the same name (otherwise, what would it return when you called hash["6"]?). If you tell us what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to craft a better solution.

Comment: If you want both values under the key '6', the value referenced by the key '6' will have to be an array that will contain both values. You could also store them in a string with a seperator like `'2,1'`.

Comment: Well here is what I am trying to achieve. I have these three numbers in an array. These are ids I am bringing back that represent inputs. The 2nd array I bring back is the values..the 2 and the 1 in the counts array are supposed to be added up to the id corresponding in order. The 2 and 1 to the 6 ID.

Comment: At the end of the day I want the corresponding id's of 6 and 11 to have values of 3 and 1.

Comment: Gotcha, so it's a "total count" for each ID? I'll update my code to show that.

Comment: Wow, you are a lifesaver. Brilliant code here for what I need. If I wanted to reference the first part of that object in a for loop and the value. What would be the proper concept?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, can you post some pseudocode of what you'd be trying to do? If it's a big change, you may want to make a new question for it.

Comment: I found it Dan Wich. Nevermind. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use an object to accomplish this:

```
var obj = {};
for(var i=0, l=idOne.length; i<l; i++){
  obj[idOne[i]] = counts[i];
}
```

You can then access it by:

```
obj['6']; // -> 1
```

Comment: But `obj['6'] = '1';`

Comment: @elclanrs - Haha yes quite correct. I didn't look at the OP's full example. Just showing the concept really.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
idOne = ["6", "6", "11"]
counts = ["2", "1", "1"]

var dict = []; // create an empty array
$.each(idOne, function (index, value) {
    dict.push({
        key: idOne[index],
        value: counts[index]
    });
});

console.log(dict);
```

You can access the key-value pair like this:

```
$.each(dict, function (index, data) {
    console.log(data.key + " : " + data.value);
});
```